# Quiero instalar windows 10 en una maquina vieja

Tags: windows10, instalacion

Estoy intentando instalar windows 10 en una maquina vieja que tiene de chipset nforce, y me da error stop 0x1 y stop 0xc225, los dos errores he buscado en internet y es referido a drivers, es decir
cuando instalo el sistema operativo desde pendrive usb, no puedo iniciar el programa de instalacion que tira dichos errores
He intentado utilizar sysprop, que es para poder iniciar windows sin drivers, pero tampoco ha funcionado. ALguien sabe alguna manera de hacer funcionar windows 10 con dichos problemas?

La placa madre que lleva es "http://es.gigabyte.com/products/page/mb/ga-73vm-s2_10/" y un procesador de 2 nucleos de 3 ghz de velocidad es bastante veloz, con 4 gb de ram
POdrian decirme por favor que puedo hacer para instalarlo? gracias
Por cierto he probado la ram y disco rigido, y me da todo bien, incluso con una fuente nueva. La instalacion de windows xp va de maravilla, pero no puedo hacer correr la instalacion de windows 10

Comment: 3ghz de velocidad es una "maquina vieja"??? el chipset nforce es de la tarjeta grafica(entiendo) se puede quitar?

Comment: y si pruebas a actualizar los drivers? o ir a la página del fabricante a buscar info?

Comment: Hola Bernardo. Yo acabo de instalar un windows 10 en un Core 2 duo P8700 de 2.53 Ghz y me funciono correctamente, tanto instalación como el sistema finalmente instalado, sin embargo con otro Core 2 Duo de otro cliente, la semana pasada, fui incapaz de instalarselo por continuos problemas durante la instalación, finalmente se tuvo que quedar con windows 7 y funciono a la primera.

Comment: NO SE PUEDE. El core tiene que ser de 64 bits y aun si lo consigues no va a andar con tan poca RAM.

Comment: @Orici tiene razón. Respecto a la memoria, con 4GB de RAM si que puede tirar (yo tengo máquinas así) pero lento. Lo que si, que si es de 32 bits no lo vas a poder instalar.

Comment: Las afirmaciones de Orici y Peppo son falsas. Windows 10 se puede instalar  en ordenadores de 32bits y a partir de 1Gb de RAM.   (en el caso de 64bits se precisan 2gb de RAM). A veces no entiendo de donde sacan ciertas afirmaciones... INFORMACIÓN OFICIAL: https://www.microsoft.com/es-es/windows/windows-10-specifications#primaryR2

Comment: Voto por cerrar esta pregunta como tema no relacionado porque  no versa sobre un problema de programación, por favor leer [ask]

Comment: @Aprendiz, en este caso tal vez si es una pregunta propiada, teniendo en cuenta esta otra sección o sugerencia https://es.stackoverflow.com/help/on-topic Excepto si instalar WINDOWS 10 no es cnosiderado como una herramienta para poder programar en SO de microsoft.

Comment: No me lo parece ya que la duda o problema expuesto no tiene que ver con programación, es una duda me parece fuera de tema pero igual para eso es la votación para que la comunidad opine, pues el que no funcione la tarjeta madre también impediría que se programe @JuanJoseBurgosVeiga

Comment: Se armó un buen debate. Si consideramos los conocimientos que hay que aplicar para solucionar este problema, si se requiere el conocimiento de XML y estructuras inf, además se necesita saber de hardware, software, e información del sistema operativo como requerimientos mininos y estructuras de SO. En fin, creo que la solución es colocar los drivers pre-instalables al sistema operativo. Estoy buscando información al respecto